# AngularJS: isolated scope in directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to write an AngularJS directive and bind a scope attribute (controller scope) to a template element.
I have an isolate scope for my directive.
It doesn't work. Could someone please help me ?

Regards,
Agnes.

Here is my code below:

**JavaScript:**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.val = "Helena Parker";
});

app.directive("helloWorld", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      name: "@",
      val: "@"
    },
    template: "<div>a {{name}} a</div>",

    link: function linkFn(scope, lElement, attrs) {
          scope.$watch(attrs.name2, function(value) {
             lElement.text(lElement.text() + 'b ' + value + ' b');
          });
    }
  };
});
```

**Html:**

<
hello-world name="John Smith" name2="val">

**Result is:**
a John Smith ab undefined b

**Expected result is:**
a John Smith ab Helena Parker b

Comment: attrs.name2 is not in the scope so scope has nothing  to watch  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For value your should use "=" instead of "@" in your scope object.
Moreover for your scope define "name2" instead of val. or link val to name2 attributes and i don't understand why you are using a $watch on val, data binding does the trick so so do this

```
app.directive("helloWorld", function() {
 return {
   restrict: "E",
   scope: {
     name: "=",
     val: "=name2"
   },
   template: "<div>a {{name}} a b {{val}} b </div>",
   link: function linkFn(scope, lElement, attrs) {

    }
 };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to whatch attribure

```
scope.$watch(function() { return attrs.name2}, function(value) {
    lElement.text(lElement.text() + 'b ' + value + ' b');
});
```

But best way is simple to bind it with double way binging.

```
scope: {
  name: "@",
  val: "@"
  name2: "=?"
}
```

And then

```
scope.$watch('name2', function(value) {
    lElement.text(lElement.text() + 'b ' + value + ' b');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done that and got what I wanted (a John Smith ab Helena Parker b).

**JavaScript:**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.val = "Helena Parker";
});

app.directive("helloWorld", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      name: "@",
      val: "="
    },
    template: "<div>a {{name}} ab {{val}} b</div>"
  };
});
```

**Html:**

<
hello-world name="John Smith" val="val">